# XBMC compilation error

Tags: kodi, software-compilation

I have the lastest Raspbian version (the 3.12.24+ kernel) and i tried to compile xbmc by following this guide: http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianXBMC

All Worked until the make... I got this error:

```
CPP     xbmc/cores/dvdplayer/DVDPlayerVideo.o
In file included from /home/pi/xbmc-rbp/xbmc/windowing/egl/WinEGLPlatform.h:28:0,
                 from /home/pi/xbmc-rbp/xbmc/windowing/egl/WinSystemGLES.h:29,
                 from /home/pi/xbmc-rbp/xbmc/windowing/WindowingFactory.h:40,
                 from DVDPlayerVideo.cpp:24:
/home/pi/xbmc-rbp/xbmc/windowing/egl/WinEGLPlatformRaspberryPI.h:61:3: error: ‘EGL_DISPMANX_WINDOW_T’ does not name a type
make[1]: *** [DVDPlayerVideo.o] Erreur 1
make: *** [xbmc/cores/dvdplayer/DVDPlayer.a] Erreur 2
```

And i didn't found how to solve it, somebody can help me ?

Comment: If you just want to install xbmc, maybe this helps. I installed from here. It's an inofficial repository with the packages. http://michael.gorven.za.net/raspberrypi/xbmc

Answer (score 1):

I got around the same error by adding the following code to xbmc/windowing/egl/WinEGLPlatformRaspberryPI.h:

`typedef struct { 
    DISPMANX_ELEMENT_HANDLE_T element; 
    int width; 
    int height; 
 } EGL_DISPMANX_WINDOW_T;`

(Credit to http://wiki.mitsted.dk/?page=RPi_Resources)